# Insert php variable in mysql query (name of table)

Tags: php, mysql

I looked for my problem in the archive but the solutions reported were not good for my case.
I can not understand the right syntax to insert a php variable instead of the table name:

```
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO galleria1(contatore, immagine) VALUES ('', '".$filename."')";
```

where instead of galleria1 I have to enter the $gallery php variable.
Thanks to those who can help me.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: you might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php to prevent SQL injection

Comment: IMHO It's not a question for stackoverflow. You should definitely read manuals. For example a link, provided by VisioN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do like following:

```
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO `" . $gallery . "`(contatore, immagine) VALUES ('', '".$filename."')";
```

And make sure that `$gallery` variable has the value in it actually.
So for debugging you can simply `echo $insert_sql;` to check if sql is in right syntax.

**Important Note**

Above code is very **not safe** regarding **SQL Injection**, so please check following article:

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

,to learn how to handle the case.

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

With this syntax:

```
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO " . $gallery . "(contatore, immagine) VALUES ('', '".$filename."')";
```

I have this error message:

> database error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(contatore, immagine) VALUES ('', '03.jpg')' at line 1

If I change $galleria with the name of table in database (galleria1) the code is ok.

Comment: Check my answer as I made some revision. From the error message, I feel that $gallery is empty variable without any value. You can simply echo the $insert_sql first, to see if it is in correct way.

Comment: Thanks, I was wrong, instead of writing $galleria, I had written $galleria1 that did not exist. $galleria has a value inside it and now it works.

Comment: you are welcome. you can accept my answer above then. :D